# IBM DB2 content manager database related query

Tags: db2

In IBM DB2 content manager 8.6 , which all tables between two databases RMDB(Resource manager DB2 database)and ICMNLSDB (Library server DB2 database) are linked to eachother to retrieve data stored.

Is Itemid column from table ICMADMIN.ICMSTITEMS001001 is referred as obj_itemid from rmadmin.rmobjects table as we don't find any table which is referred between eachother..we need to retrieve the path of files stored in filesystem by IBM content manager.

Comment: This is not a Db2 question. It is a question asking about the data mdel internals of the __application__ known as Content-Manager. If you do not find the answer in the knowledge-centre https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/content-manager/8.7.0?topic=reference-system-tables   ,  then open a ticket with IBM .  Stackoverflow might be the wrong channel for this kind of question.

Comment: Thank you Mao ,i will address this question to correct group ..